# take the max of a list of string numbers

Tags: python

I have a list like this `lst = ['1.8.6.8', '1.8.8.879', '1.8.8.880', '1.8.10.883', '1.8.10.884']`. I would like to take the max such that it evaluates each block separated by `.` independently, and then return `1.8.10.884`. `max(lst)` returns `1.8.8.880`. Is there a neat way to do this without splitting it by `.` and then looping through each subset?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "max such that it evaluates each block separated by `.`  independently"? Do you want the strings to be compared lexicographically w.r.t the `.`-deliminated numbers, or do you want to take the element-wise max of each position?

Answer (score 2):

`max(lst)` returns `1.8.8.880` because strings are compared in lexicographical order.

To compare them as integers, you'll have to split by `.` and convert the elements to integers. However, you can use tuple / list comparisons to do the sorting instead of looping through each subset. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3] > [1, 1, 3] # True
[1, 2, 3] > [1, 2, 4] # False
```

However, this doesn't account for the length of the lists: the list that contains the smaller element first is picked as the smaller list.

```
[1, 2, 3] > [1, 1, 100, 1000] # Gives True
```

To get around this, we'll return a tuple containing the length of the list, and the list itself. Also, we'll use the `key` argument to the `max` function:

```
def convert_function(elem):
    vals = [int(a) for a in elem.split('.')]
    return (len(vals), vals)

lst = ['1.8.68', '1.8.8.879', '1.8.8.880', '1.8.10.883', '1.8.10.884']
max(lst, key=convert_function) # gives '1.8.10.884'
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting each string on `.` and converting the fields to integers.

```
>>> t1 = [[int(x) for x in y.split('.')] for y in lst]
>>> t1
[[1, 8, 68], [1, 8, 8, 879], [1, 8, 8, 880], [1, 8, 10, 883], [1, 8, 10, 884]]
```

Then zip the tuples and map `max` over the result.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> t2 = [max(x) for x in zip_longest(*t1, fillvalue=0)]
>>> t2
[1, 8, 68, 884]
```

Finally, join the elements of `t2` into a single string.

```
>>> '.'.join(map(str, t2))
'1.8.68.884'
```

I leave it as an exercise to combine these steps  into a single expression.